# Computed property triggers before onBeforeMount

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am getting an error because my computed property is expecting for some variable to be full of data, but I do my data loading in `onBeforeMount` which for some reason is being triggered **AFTER** my computed property.

**MY THEORY WHY THIS IS HAPPENING:**

When I remove my watcher the problem goes away.
Watcher triggers the computation of the `"myComputedProperty"` because it needs the old value so it can compare it to the new value and it does that as soon as `watch()` is called.

**Does that mean I have to register my watchers in onBeforeMount to avoid this type of behavior?**

Relevant code:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch, computed, onBeforeMount } from 'vue';
onBeforeMount(() => {
   console.log("onBeforeMount")
   valueThatIsFilledInBeforeMount = 1;
});
const myComputedProperty = computed(() => {
   //some code
   return valueThatIsFilledInBeforeMount + 1;
})
watch(myComputedProperty , async (newValue, oldValue) => {
   //some code
})

</script>
```

Stuff I am using:

- "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
- "axios": "^0.21.1",
- "fast-xml-parser": "^4.0.10",
- "pinia": "^2.0.11",
- "quasar": "^2.6.0",
- "vue": "^3.0.0",
- "vue-router": "^4.0.0",
- "xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.18.11/xlsx-0.18.11.tgz"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try initialising your valueThatIsFilledInBeforeMount in your data Export?

I tested it with my config and unless im not exporting my valueToCompute with an initial value (0 or null or smth.) my computed value works just fine:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      valueBeforeMount: null,
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.valueBeforeMount = 1;
  },
  computed: {
    valueBeforeMountComp() {
      return this.valueBeforeMount + 1;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    valueBeforeMountComp: function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal) // Should be 2
      console.log(oldVal) // Should be 1
    },
  }
}
```

At least if i get your problem right.

Comment: No, wrong example. Your watcher watches DATA, my watcher watches COMPUTED property.

Also, in your example "computed( )" should be replaced with "computed :" because computed is a object, not a function

Comment: The computed is a typo, my fault and i took the wrong property to watch. But if i change my watcher to watch the computed property, it works nonetheless

Comment: Open this linked and open the console with F12. You will see that the order of execution. Computed is first.

https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kstuwyAQRX9lxCpRE1C6dK1KbddVF5W6YkPscewIA+KRVIry78XGjhO3jWQZBu6ceTAn8mIMPQQkGcldYRvjn7nCb6OthxIrEaSHE1cApfBisUx7AIs+WDVaAAchA75ipS2+66B8BipIuUrX524598Z2kkywQiunJVKpdwtOriScLJ+4mrwL3ZrgscxGz3nYtyiYuHPy6J6wSTEU4uvG0TkNHmAzCFP89D8KX9R3U8igCqrwjVYLhccvIVegZRnXf1Prmdd5XV8nxhIYg89aB1nGNsLjX8oxyo1yc1MCV/HL2eWto+GxNVJ4jBZAXm+ePwx2LcGRnbN42HldlGRFmrYbknUrDN07reIA9bXx4cJxcukRJ3HCOpuT2nvjMsZcVXRjt3dU2x2LO2pj85oWKbp2vbX66NBGMCfDEPUMFg8PaNcWVYkW7T3mTPqLO3aDnH8AxeEB6g==

Comment: I dont think there is a go around for beforeMounted to call before the computed property reacts to the change of its dependencies. So if you get your data from an axios call or something you need to give your computed value a suitable default value it can work with before it gets its desired data.

Comment: You can register you watchers in your beforeMount (if you are using composition API, I don't know how would you do that with options API)